# When is onDestroyView method called in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, adapter, mopub

When you create a **ListView**, we use the method **onCreateView**. Is there any method that is called when the **View** (item) is **destroyed**?

I want destroy moPub Ad View.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` works with `View`s. There is a method `getView()` in the `Adapter` interface. So the concept is as follows:

The `ListView` wants to show a new row so it asks the adapter to provide it. The adapter can be passed a **convertView** instance. This is a *recycled* view - a view that was used previously used but is no longer visible. This way the adapter can just update the values of the existing view and return it (performance optimization) or create a new view and set it up. The `ListView` keeps a pool of views - visible views and views that can be used as **convertViews**. The `ListView` is not responsible for creating or destroying the view instances (this will be a bad design). It only consumes them.

So if you want to do something when the `View` is destroyed, you probably have to implement your custom `View` and there implement the `onDestroy()` method.

Hope this was useful :)

Answer (score 1):

OnCreatView is a lifecycle method in a fragment not the list view. There is however an ondestroyview lifecycle method for fragments too. You can read more about fragment lifecycles here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html